Why did Fremen laugh here?
Stilgar advises Paul to be brave, simple, and direct, without showing off,
and warns him that the trial's outcome, decided by Shai-Hulud, is a matter
of life and death - become Fremen or face death:

Shishakli: Hey, Muad'Dib! Don't embarrass us! Call a big one!
(Fremen Laughs)

Why did Fremen laugh here?

In the original novel, it's Stilgar who has this line. Paul decides that asking Stilgar asking him to call a particularly large worm is a mark of ritual; the bigger the worm, the better an omen it is for the tribe and for that Fremen in specific.

Paul felt the warm smoothness of the plastic as he accepted the
thumper.
“Shishakli has your hooks,” Stilgar said. “He’ll hand them to you as
you step out onto that dune over there.” He pointed to his right.
“Call a big maker, Usul. Show us the way.”
Paul marked the tone of Stilgar’s voice — half ritual and half that of
a worried friend.


In the movie there doesn't seem to be any malice in what Shishakli is saying. Paul is very old to be riding his first worm and everyone present has already done it. The situation is dangerous for Paul and tense for his friends, but it's pretty mundane for everyone else there, hence why they're sitting around having a picnic.
Shishakli and his buddies are amusing themselves by shouting vague encouragement in Paul's direction, as he, hopefully, doesn't make a complete arse of himself (or die).

Basically: "Are you telling me that you, a man of thirty years, never drove a tractor? Everybody in this village knows how to drive a tractor. My twelve year old daughter knows how to drive a tractor! Let's find you a tractor, the bigger the better!"
